# Is there a way to lock VertexBuffers in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, msdn

Looking at the MSDN documentation, I can't find a way to lock VertexBuffers so that I can change their data while on the device. Is this possible in XNA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options for modifying the contents of vertex buffers in XNA:

- `VertexBuffer` has a [`SetData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198836.aspx) member. You can only safely use this outside of `Draw` in any case where you may activate [Predicated Tiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464139.aspx) (so it's good practice to simply always do it outside of Draw).
- [`DynamicVertexBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.dynamicvertexbuffer.aspx) is like `VertexBuffer`, but faster when settings its contents. However it is susceptible to the graphics device being lost, and this condition must be handled. Also take a look at [`SetDataOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.setdataoptions.aspx).
- [`DrawUserPrimitives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.drawuserprimitives.aspx) (and [indexed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.drawuserprimitives.aspx) version). This has the advantages of not affecting Predicated Tiling, and not causing the the command buffer to flush for small numbers of primitives.

There is more information on MSDN about [Dynamically Updating Vertices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975156.aspx). And [this thread](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/35183.aspx) on the XNA forums may also be worth reading.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a lot of good info. One other question: Is it ALWAYS safe to call SetData on a VertexBuffer outside Draw?

Comment: @blachniet: Yes (actually it's a command-buffer thing, but, yes, outside Draw in the simple case). You sound like you are coming from a DirectX background: if need to be absolutely certain about what XNA is doing behind the scenes, you can always run your game through PIX.